# JSR223 Preprocessor generating the same value when the thread runs in loop

Tags: jmeter

Context: Want to generate unique and different value when the thread runs in loop.
Currently it is generating the same value.

Script Inside JSR223 Preprocessor,

```
String subscribeSchemaNamePreProcesser="agent-Perf-${__Random(1,99999,)}"
log.info("Schema Name --------------->"+subscribeSchemaNamePreProcesser)
vars.put("subscribeSchemaNamePreProcesser", subscribeSchemaNamePreProcesser)
```

When run with number of threads more than 1(i.e. 2 thread 1 loop), it is generating different value

[image]

When run with number of loops more than 1 (i.e. 1 thread 2 loop), it is generating the same value (want to fix it)

[image]

[image]

anything I missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts, they will be cached and only first occurrence will be used for subsequent calls.

You need to change this line:

```
String subscribeSchemaNamePreProcesser="agent-Perf-${__Random(1,99999,)}"
```

to this one:

```
String subscribeSchemaNamePreProcesser = "agent-Perf-" + org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 99999)
```

More information:

- [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the issue, one more quick question off the topic from this question, I am running another thread with the same configuration where I am using the value which I am creating through this JSR223 preprocessor. Iam seeing the same value for all the request when I am running the next thread group in the same loop. Any clue how to fix it ?